# VB.Net Can't connect to cloud mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have mysql database setup on 000webhost.com but i can't connect to it (NO CONNECTION). I am using vb.net in visual studio 2013. Can someone tell me how to connect to the cloud then? My project is a application not a website. Here is my imports:

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

And here is my connection lines: (i use 2 database)

1 Database PRIMARY:

```
"server=mysql7.000webhost.com;userid=a4504691_root;password=HIDDEN;database=a4504691_syscore"
```

Secondary:

```
"server=mysql7.000webhost.com;userid=a4504691_root2;password=HIDDEN;database=a4504691_sysinfo"
```

Connection to my localhost database does work. (localhost). How do i connect to the cloud ? i think everything is ok. Here is a example what it gives me when i create database in 000webhost.com :

```
$mysql_host = "mysql7.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a4504691_systemblah";
$mysql_user = "a4504691_blah";
$mysql_password = "balahblah";
```

No port thats all information it gives me:

```
Domain  deathlairappdb.netii.net
Username    a4504691
Password    ******
Disk Usage  0.02 / 1500.0 MB
Bandwidth   100000 MB (100GB)
Home Root   /home/a4504691
Server Name server28.000webhost.com
IP Address  31.170.160.92
Apache ver. 2.2.19 (Unix)
PHP version 5.2.*
MySQL ver.  5.1
Activated On    2015-02-04 10:32
Status  Active
```

Comment: Look like Port is missing. Can you check again.

Comment: It dosen't give me the port thats all the information i have: Domain deathlairappdb.netii.net
Username a4504691
Password ******
Disk Usage 0.02 / 1500.0 MB
Bandwidth 100000 MB (100GB)
Home Root /home/a4504691
Server Name server28.000webhost.com
IP Address 31.170.160.92
Apache ver. 2.2.19 (Unix)
PHP version 5.2.*
MySQL ver. 5.1
Activated On 2015-02-04 10:32
Status Active

Comment: Ok if you don't know how to fix the problem could you tell me good free mysql host that works?

Comment: Moderators or admins remove this question. This wont have answer.